# how to give path to ipa file in xamrin ui test

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamrin.ui test to test ios IPA file.
I don't have its code. Where to give path to ipa file in xamrinui test?
I try to search blog but I am unable to find how to do the setup

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `.app` bundle use the `iOSAppConfigurator.AppBundle` to assign the local path of the app:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = ConfigureApp.iOS.AppBundle("/your/local/Path/bundle.app").StartApp();
    }
```

If you have an Calabash-enabled `.ipa` installed on your device, you can use `iOSAppConfigurator.InstalledApp` to define the bundle id of the app:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = ConfigureApp.iOS.InstalledApp("com.sushihangover.MyGreatApp").StartApp();
    }
```

re: [AppBundle](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.AppBundle/p/System.String/) / [InstalledApp](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.InstalledApp/)